# AsyncTask return file not found though file exists

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am having a problem with `AsyncTask` class in Android Studio. It keeps giving me message "file not found" when the file exists for sure. Below is my code snippet:

```
public class PhpInsertProduct extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;
    private Context context;
    private HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Snackbar snackbar;
    private static String PHP_INSERT_PRODUCT = "http://www.example.com/phpexample.php"; //this file exists but Android Studio keeps giving me "file not found" error for this file
    private String inputLine, query, result, categoryName, name, price, image, saleStartTime, saleDuration, salePrice, desc, createdAt, createdBy;
    private String[] ftpImagePaths;
    private StringBuffer response;
    private TextView tvSnackbarTextView;
    private Uri.Builder uriBuilder;
    private URL url;
    private View snackbarView, view;

    public PhpInsertProduct(Context context, View view, ProgressDialog progressDialog, String categoryName, String[] ftpImagePaths)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.view = view;
        this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
        this.categoryName = categoryName;
        this.ftpImagePaths = ftpImagePaths;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {
        name = args[0];
        price = args[1];
        image = args[2];
        saleStartTime = args[3];
        saleDuration = args[4];
        salePrice = args[5];
        desc = args[6];
        createdAt = args[7];
        createdBy = args[8];
        try
        {
            url = new URL(PHP_INSERT_PRODUCT);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");
            uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("name", name)
                    .appendQueryParameter("price", price)
                    .appendQueryParameter("image", image)
                    .appendQueryParameter("saleStartTime", saleStartTime)
                    .appendQueryParameter("saleDuration", saleDuration)
                    .appendQueryParameter("salePrice", salePrice)
                    .appendQueryParameter("desc", desc)
                    .appendQueryParameter("createdAt", createdAt)
                    .appendQueryParameter("createdBy", createdBy);
            query = uriBuilder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            bufferedWriter.write(query);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream())); //this is the line that triggers the error
            response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) response.append(inputLine);
            bufferedReader.close();
            result = response.toString();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        if(result.isEmpty()) new PhpGetItemId(context, view, progressDialog, categoryName, ftpImagePaths, null, createdAt, createdBy).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, name);
        else
        {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            FragmentAddProducts.fragmentAddProducts.setSaveInProgress(false);
            snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, context.getResources().getString(R.string.error_saving_product), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
            snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00DDFF"));
            tvSnackbarTextView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
            tvSnackbarTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF3333"));
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }
}
```

FYI, I have plenty of other AsyncTask classes similar to this and they work just fine. I am only getting error for this class and I have no idea why.
Does anyone know how to actually solve this problem?

Comment: Please share your actual url

Comment: Please share the logcat along with the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is actually server-side. The server had low PHP language version so the PHP script could not run properly on the server. However, after moved to another server with higher PHP version, the script worked OK. Problem solved.

It is, however, very unfortunate that Android Studio gave misleading error message. It said file not found while the file was exactly there. It should have given more appropriate error message, e.g.: PHP error or something along the line.